# no puedo realizar el backup de la base de datos con PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Al intentar realizar el backup de mi base de datos se presenta el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi sistema operativo es windows y estoy utilizando pgAdmin III. 
Alguien que me pueda ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo desde la consola ingresa este codigo y cambia los datos por los de tu conexion:

```
pg_dump -i -h <server> -p <puerto> -U <usuario> -F c -b -v -f <nombre_fichero> <bd>
```

y de dejo este ejemplo de mi conexion que use hace poco:

```
pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "/home/damian/backups/mibase.backup" mibase
```

este codigo yo siempre lo uso y me funciona bien

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, para ejecutar el comando debo estar en la carpeta bin? @Oscar Diaz

Comment: no necesariamente si tienes pgAdmin III dale en la parte de la consola donde se escriben las consultas si no lo tienes instalado ingresa por consola al postgrest y hay lo ejecutas

Comment: Muchas gracias, sabes que en el comando tuve que borrar el -i ya que no le reconocía, una vez realizado esto se creó el backup.

Comment: si el -i es para que ignore la version entre el comando y la base de datos me alegro que te haya funcionado